# ggplotly - date as x-axis is shown as number on hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

How can i get a date on hover instead of a number in plotly?

My sample code

```
require(plotly)
require(tidyverse)

dates <- c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92")
dat <- tibble(a = rnorm(5), b = as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y")) 

p <- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(b, a)) +
  geom_line()

ggplotly(p)
```

Results in:
I would expect b to be `Feb 01` instead of 8066. How can i get this?

[image]

Comment: closely related question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475567/r-error-in-date-visualization-of-ggplotly?rq=1 -- suggests installing the dev version of `ggplot2` from github -- otherwise, workaround suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use the basic `plot_ly` function, as in:

```
plot_ly(dat,
        x = ~b,
        y = ~a) %>% add_lines()
```

which displays the date correctly on hover.

[image]

Comment: you can also create [custom hover text](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#custom-hover-text) with `plot_ly`.  I don't use ggplotly though, so no idea how to solve in that package.